# Search by term in two columns of table and rank with count

Tags: mysql, search

I have a table, InnoDB, with columns id(int), name(varchar) and info(text). I need to search the name and info columns of the table using a given term and rank the matching records from high to low, according to the number of 'hits' in the two columns combined for each record.

I've trawled about but I've never ever done anything like this with MySQL before and find it all a little confusing... case and match etc. etc.

Can anyone offer some quick help?

This is as far as I've got:

```
SELECT count(*) as count
FROM artistmanager_artists WHERE
case when 'name' LIKE '%a%' then 1 else 0 end
+ case when 'info' LIKE '%a%' then 1 else 0 end
ORDER BY count ASC
```

('a' being the search term)

Which returns one row and one column, 'count', with a value of three... which I'm guessing is because I've got three records in the table at the mo?

I've also found and tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `artistmanager_artists`
WHERE `name` LIKE '%a%'
AND (
   `info` LIKE '%a%'
)
ORDER BY (
  (
      CASE WHEN `name` LIKE '%a%'
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
      END
  ) + (
     CASE WHEN `info` LIKE '%a%'
     THEN 1
     ELSE 0
     END
  )
) DESC
```

This returned all but one record, in no obvious order, when I KNOW the record it didn't return contains a lot of 'a'!

Comment: @RahulTripathi I've added what I've tried above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it! Thanks to @MvG for the inspiration. Since I'm much better with my PHP than I am my MySQL I solved the problem by doing the following: (I'm using Codeignite btw)

```
public function get_artists_search($search_term)
{
    $artists = array();
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT id, name, info, (name LIKE "%' . $search_term . '%") + (info LIKE "%' . $search_term . '%") AS rnk FROM artistmanager_artists ORDER BY rnk DESC');
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        // returned rows have at least one occurence in at least one of the two columns, so values are 1 or 2
        $artists[$row->id]['name'] = $row->name;
        $artists[$row->id]['info'] = $row->info;
        $artists[$row->id]['score'] = 0;
    }
    // now foreach returned row find occurence values.
    foreach($artists AS $key=>$artist)
    {
        $score_name = substr_count(strtoupper($artist['name']), strtoupper($search_term));
        $score_info = substr_count(strtoupper($artist['info']), strtoupper($search_term));
        $artists[$key]['score'] = $score_name+$score_info;
        unset($artists[$key]['name']);
        unset($artists[$key]['info']);
    }
    arsort($artists);
}
```

Which returns an array with the ids of the records as key and a rank value, sorted high to low. I tested it and it works so I'm chuffed.

Thanks to all for help with the lateral thinking!

Answer (score 3):

Thw following will rank rows by the number of columns (0 through 2) matching your term:

```
SELECT (name LIKE '%a%') + (info LIKE '%a%') AS rnk
FROM artistmanager_artists
ORDER BY rnk DESC
```

This makes use of the fact that a boolean value, like the result of `LIKE`, is represented by an integer in MySQL, 0 for false and 1 for true. So you can simply add them, without any case distinction.

If you want to find multiple counts, you'll probably have to write a stored procedure that loops over your string, as there is no basic string function that counts matches. Unless the amount of data is really large, you might be better of by computing these counts in the application instead of on the database server.

Your first code snippet simply returns the number of rows that contain an `a` in either column. This is because `COUNT` is an aggregating column, which (in the absence of a `GROUP BY`) will combine all your rows into a single row. The second snippet will only choose rows which have `a` in *both* columns, so the ordering number will always be `2`, causing the apparent lack of ordering.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works but only up to a maximum of 2, as in the number of columns, out of the 2, that contain matches, as you said. Can you give me any pointers on the stored procedure route or how I might do this with php to acheieve the desired result as this is what I'm after. Thanks.